# Looking for tilt switch solution

Tags: switches

How would you go about making sure your device stays ON for 180 degrees and OFF for the other 180 degrees? +- 20 in each direction is fine.

I have a water pump that I would like to turn into a compact water scooter. Naturally balanced it would be off but when turned it would turn on.

I am trying to avoid gyroscopes and programming for the sake of keeping things simple to repair.

Any ideas?

Comment: A mercury switch or a ball bearing switch with a control on its rotation.

Comment: Surely you can get some sort of analog-output accelerometer, no? You could also include programming while keeping repair easy by having the programming be on a popular, easily accessible development board, like an Arduino, and you can use a socketed accelerometer or gyro to make it easily replaceable.

Comment: Why bother with all this tilt switching if simple dead man's switch (a.k.a. "kill cord", mandatory on many power boats) is sufficient. By the time your scooter is upside down you yourself are surely not anywhere on it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use an electric heater anti-tilt switch designed to turn off an electric heater if it gets knocked over. Typical spec is

> Fall-Protect  Action Angle:30-50°;Reset Angle:>15°;The Error of Action Angle:±5°

They are available with 16A contacts to directly switch high current, or gold-plated contacts for signal-level switching. Photo from Xiamen Universal, but there are other makers, and you'd need to evaluate them carefully.

[image]

Comment: And even if you can't get one with a 180° range of "on", you could always mount a couple at different angles and use simple logic (a couple 74HCxx or even just a couple relays if you want to go really old-school!) to require they all be off before your system considers it as "off".

Answer (score 1):

Buy a pipe, neodymium magnet and Hall sensor/proximity sensor. Build according picture below. Enclose the both ends of the pipe. Put some rubber on both ends to damp the magnet hits.

You can use a metal ball (move more easy in pipe) with some sort of sensors.

[image]

Comment: This seems more complicated than a ball bearing in a tube with a button on one end. Why the magnet and hall sensor?

Comment: It is, but more reliable as it avoids contact problems especially in high humidity environment.